# Run SSIS Package via SQL AGENT job

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, excel, ssis

I am good with SSIS and I created a package which will load excel files into SQL SERVER  tables.

I wrote the C# code to extract only the first sheet name, and then package will load the data present this first sheet(only).

The package works fine when I run it through BIDS. But the same package throws error at the C# code step when I run this package through SQL AGENT JOB.

I have seen many posts suggesting that this may be because of using `Microsoft.interop.excel` references inside the c# code.

Is there any alternate way in C# to extract the first sheet name(not based on ascending order) of an excel file with out using the inter-op library.

Alternatively how may I configure SQL AGENT job to run successfully when using inter-op inside the code?

My server is 64 bit.

I tried creating  "Desktop" folder in "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\"

> Error:Description: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.     at
>   ST_ecfa668f250a45e18c95639c9ffd64d4.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()     ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---     at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)     at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)     at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture,
>   Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)     at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags
>   bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs,
>   ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[]
>   namedParams)     at System.Type.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args, CultureInfo
>   culture)     at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
>   End Error  Error: 2015-02-27 11:24:00.23     Code: 0x00000001
>   Source: User Mail      Description:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
>   Could not open a connection to SQL Server)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean
>   ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean
>   trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, SqlConnection
>   owningObject)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64
>   timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String
>   host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance,
>   SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   Int64 timerStart)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection
>   owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String
>   newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo,
>   String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool,
>   DbConnection owningConnection)     at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) 
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owning...  The package execution fa...  The step failed

The C# code-

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ST_ecfa668f250a45e18c95639c9ffd64d4.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion


        public void Main()
        {   /*Passing the file path via User::File_Name Variable*/
            string FileName = Dts.Variables["User::File_Name"].Value.ToString();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelBook = null;
            try
            {
                xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                excelBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName, Type.Missing,
                                                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                string[] excelSheets = new string[excelBook.Worksheets.Count];
                int i = 0;
                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet wSheet in excelBook.Worksheets)
                {
                    excelSheets[i] = wSheet.Name;
                    i++;
                }
                Dts.Variables["User::WorkSheetName"].Value = excelSheets[0] + "$";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                excelBook.Close(false, FileName, null);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelBook);
                string error = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                excelBook.Close(false, FileName, null);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelBook);
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the Excel interop registered in the GAC on the server? Does the service running SQL Agent have same read/write permissions to all pertinent folders and files?

Comment: Yes, Sql Agent have admin permissions on the folders

Comment: I don't understand, why StackOverflow marking negative to this question, Is it sounds as stupid Question to them?

Comment: Try creating this folder:   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop

Comment: Thanks @Sorrell... I did this and package running successfully....But can you please explain the logic behind this

Answer (score 1):

Try creating this folder: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop`

[See this link for more details](http://clausoncode.dk/wp/?p=180)

Comment: Thanks for providing me the resources. But the link doesn't explain the pro's and con's when placing "Desktop" folder inside the  "Systemprofile" folder. I am investing the same on my end and will update if i found a right solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must be running the BIDS on 32-bit machine that's why package is running successfully. On your UAT server, please configure the package to run in 32-bit mode in SQL job step. To do this, please modify the SQL job step in which you have configured the SSIS package -

1) Goto **Execution Options** tab

2) Select check-box against **Use 32 bit runtime**

It should resolve your issue.

Comment: I took all the care to execute the SSISpackage in UAT SERVER(64-bit). I also tried executing the job in UAT SERVER through BIDS....It is working fine..Also if i disabled my script component and ran the job in sql agent, then also working fine. It keeps failing only if i enabled the script component and ran the package through SQL job

Answer (score -2):

Goal to have a SQL Job SSIS Package with C3 script that dynamically created excel files on a network share. I was able to run the package by From the SQL Server Directly from the ssisdb using a proxy account. However failed to run as a job. Finally, after a long period of frustration. Thanks to the following link [success](https://bharathkumaran.wordpress.com/2011/10/25/running-excel-from-a-windows-service/).